# Executing command line using "Runtime.getRuntime().exec()"

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line

I'm having a problem while executing a command line from Java code.
This is the code I use, and under the code are the errors I got.
I also tried using `ProcessBuilder` but I got the same errors.

Ps: I am running the program on Windows.

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        Process compilerProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("clafer -k -m choco clafer.cfr);

        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                compilerProcess.getInputStream()));
            String s = null;
            while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
             System.out.print(s);        }  
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // To have access to the text generated by the compiler.


}

}
```

The error:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "echo": CreateProcess error=2, the 
  specified file is not found
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
at eqe.Test.main(Test.java:12)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, the specified file 
is not found
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
... 5 more
```

Comment: Windows doesn't have `echo`.

Comment: in the cmd, it does...but this is not the problem here.

Comment: It's a built-in `cmd` command. Not an external program. On *NIX, it's a standalone program.

Comment: so for example when I use the command help in the java class, then it does work...so why not other command line that work perfectly on cmd

Comment: @Joe17 If you have the ability to, feel free to answer your own question for others.

Comment: Of course, with pleasure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem. I simply put the command line into new String[] and worked.
Here is the solution for using to command line that allows you to execute long command line.

```
Process compilerProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"clafer","-k","-m","choco","clafer.cfr" });
```